# Freshly Provisioned Cent-OS occupies a lot of space for "/dev/mapper/centos-root"

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, disk-space

I created a fresh VM, however I started facing space issues as soon as it got created. From the `du` and `lsblk` command I see `/dev/mapper/centos-root` is occupying a lot of space. I tried running tree command on root to filter all files occupying large space. But the command takes forever.

How do I figure out what exactly is occupying space and delete them from system.

Here is the output of command.

```
[root@hpmaincs mapper]# lsblk --output NAME,KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME            KNAME TYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT
fd0             fd0   disk    4K
sda             sda   disk  100G
├─sda1          sda1  part    1G /boot
└─sda2          sda2  part   99G
  ├─centos-root dm-0  lvm    50G /
  ├─centos-swap dm-1  lvm   7.9G [SWAP]
  └─centos-home dm-2  lvm  41.1G /home
sdb             sdb   disk  100G
sr0             sr0   rom  1024M
[root@hpmaincs mapper]# df -H
Filesystem                                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root                         54G   54G   21k 100% /
devtmpfs                                       8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                          8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                          8.4G  801M  7.6G  10% /run
tmpfs                                          8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                                      1.1G  228M  836M  22% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home                         45G   38M   45G   1% /home
ytr.itm.com:/Media                             34T   26T  8.0T  77% /root/cvmedia
tmpfs                                          1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper disk space analyzer. The most barebones one, `du`, is probably installed by default. You could use it like this:

```
$ sudo du --one-file-system --human-readable --max-depth=1 /
4.5G    /usr
38M     /etc
46G     /var
8.5K    /backup
188K    /mnt
118M    /opt
50G     /
```

In my example we see `/var` is big, so let’s go there (with short options this time):

```
$ sudo du -xhd1 /var
1.7G    /var/lib
22K     /var/net-snmp
8.5K    /var/local
236M    /var/log
8.5K    /var/empty
31K     /var/db
75K     /var/syslog
8.5K    /var/games
6.6M    /var/state
44G     /var/cache
313K    /var/smbversion
212K    /var/tmp
332K    /var/spool
22K     /var/named
8.5K    /var/opt
46G     /var
```

Lots of cached stuff!

A more user-friendly solution is `ncdu`, an interactive version of `du`:

```
$ ncdu -x /
ncdu 2.3 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
--- / --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   45.1 GiB [###########] /var
    4.5 GiB [#          ] /usr
  117.1 MiB [           ] /opt
   37.9 MiB [           ] /etc
  187.5 KiB [           ] /mnt
e   8.5 KiB [           ] /backup
    4.5 KiB [           ]  dead.letter
@ 512.0   B [           ]  sbin
@ 512.0   B [           ]  lib64
@ 512.0   B [           ]  lib
@ 512.0   B [           ]  bin
>   0.0   B [           ] /tmp
>   0.0   B [           ] /tank
>   0.0   B [           ] /sys
>   0.0   B [           ] /srv
>   0.0   B [           ] /run
>   0.0   B [           ] /root
>   0.0   B [           ] /proc
>   0.0   B [           ] /keys
>   0.0   B [           ] /home
>   0.0   B [           ] /hd2
*Total disk usage:  49.7 GiB   Apparent size:  53.2 GiB   Items: 344,334
```

You can interactively drill down, and you get a relative size indicator (although boring in my example).

`ncdu` is available in most distributions’ package feeds, but seeing how your partition is full, you wouldn’t be able to install it.

Using `-x`/`--one-file-system` is important on both, because you are concerned with a specific filesystem and nothing else. If you don’t use it, it will start scanning the multi-terabyte network resource mounted at `/root/cvmedia`!

Comment: just like in windows I can merge the partitions, how can I merge root, swap and home partitions here?

Comment: It’s actually more like “Just like in Windows, you _cannot_ merge partitions”. You can get rid of `/home` as a separate partition and because of LVM you can even use that space for `/`. You’ll have to do it manually though. There is no merging. Swap is something else altogether. // But maybe attempt to clean up instead, 50 GiB is a tremendous amount of data.